# split is not a function

Tags: angular, split, angular2-forms

So i tried to split my abstract control value on the point of . cause its a currency

but i still gets a error

this is the code

```
@Directive({
    selector: '[NumberValidate][ngModel]',
    providers: [
        { provide: NG_VALIDATORS, useExisting: forwardRef(() => NumberValidator), multi: true }
    ]
})
export class NumberValidator implements Validator {

    constructor( @Attribute('NumberValidate') public NumberValidate: string,
        @Attribute('reverse') public reverse: string) {
    }

    validate(control: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: any; } {
        const DATE_REGEX = /([\-\+]{0,1}\d[\d\.\,]*[\.\,][\d\.\,]*\d+)/;


        if ((control.value && control.value <= 0) || (control.value != null && DATE_REGEX.test(control.value) && control.value.split('.')[1] != null && control.value.split('.')[1].length > 2)){
            return { 'incorrectNumberFormat': true };
        }
        return null;
    }



}
```

this is the error

> error_handler.js:54 EXCEPTION: Error in ./RegisterForm class
>   RegisterForm - inline template:200:28 caused by: control.value.split
>   is not a function

Comment: What do you get for `console.log(control.value)`?

Comment: when i put 1.0 it don't throws an error and when i enter 1.003 it throws the error ... the console gives my the right value of the input, cause it worked before, but my college tried to make an extension on it

Comment: And does it **only** output the correct value or do you get `null` as well?
What's the printed value immediately before the exception is thrown?

Comment: when i push "." it gives a null in console and if i put "," it gives the first value again whitout the "," and the moment i type anothe number after, then it throws an error

Comment: That's somehow too much information. What's the last value in the console immediately before the error? (when the `console.log(...)` is added before the line that causes the error)

Comment: is it possible the fault that the input is a number and not a text so its not a string, and the split only works on a string ?

Comment: Should be easy to test by using `('' + control.value).split(.)`

Comment: value = 1.3 but the validator runs everytime i push a button

Comment: just fixed it with a regex, much bether

Comment: hmm didn't fixed it, can't find a working regex

Comment: please create a plunker to demonstrate your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i made a regex to test the input and didn't need the split anymore, i think the problem is on the fact that the input type is a number and not a string... split can only be use on a string and not on a number. that is what i think